# how can I add a white space within a characther vector in r?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a sequence of dates in character ("2018-09-032018-09-09" "2018-09-102018-09-16" .....) and I would add a white space after the 10th digit. As a final result, I would obtain the following  "2018-09-03 2018-09-09" "2018-09-10 2018-09-16"...
I guess the gsub fuction can help but I don't know how to implement it
Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the first 10 digits and then add the space

```
sub("^(.{10})(.*)", "\\1 \\2", dates)
```

-output

```
[1] "2018-09-03 2018-09-09" "2018-09-10 2018-09-16"
```

NOTE:   We used `sub` and that was only necessary along with the fact that i specified the start (`^`) character.

#### data

```
dates <- c("2018-09-032018-09-09", "2018-09-102018-09-16")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract_all` with this `'\\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'` regex which is for YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(dates, '\\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'))
```

output:

```
 "2018-09-03" "2018-09-09" "2018-09-10" "2018-09-16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
gsub('(.{10})(.*)','\\1 \\2' ,c("2018-09-032018-09-09", "2018-09-102018-09-16"))
[1] "2018-09-03 2018-09-09" "2018-09-10 2018-09-16"
```